# Mapping self-intersections of a transformed LineString

Tags: python, intersection, shapely, linestring, self-intersection

I’m using shapely to solve a problem in physic. My problem can be represented in 2D with a LineString. In order to solve my problem I need to :

1. Apply a transformation to the original LineString
2. Find the self-intersections of this new LineString
3. Identify where those intersection points refer to on the original LineString.

Here is a simplified example. I can do step 1 and 2 but I don't know how to efficiently archive step 3 especially when the space transformation is complex.

[image: Illustration of the original and transformed LineString with self-intersections]

In general I’m wondering if there is an efficient way of finding all the points on the original LineString who are located on self-intersections on the transformed LineString? Assuming the direct-tranformation is rather simple to compute compared to the inverse-transformation.

Here is the code of my example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-"

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shapely as sh


### Contruction of base shape ###

# Polygon
c0 = sh.Point(0,0).buffer(2, quad_segs=100)
c1 = sh.Point(-1.5,0).buffer(1, quad_segs=100)
c2 = sh.Point(1.5,0).buffer(1, quad_segs=100)
c3 = c0.difference(c1.union(c2))

# original LineString
b = c3.boundary

# plot of the original LineString
x = np.array([b[0] for b in b.coords])
y = np.array([b[1] for b in b.coords])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12,3))
axs[0].set_title('original')
axs[0].plot(x,y)


## Construction of the transformed shape (step 1)

# transformation
f = 2.3
X = np.sin(f*x)
Y = np.sin(f*y)
B = sh.LineString([(Xi, Yi) for Xi, Yi in zip(X,Y)])
P0 = sh.Point(X[0], Y[0]) 

# plot of the transformed LineString
axs[1].set_title('transformed with intersect.')
axs[1].plot(X,Y)


## identification of the intersections on transformed shape (step 2)

S = sh.unary_union(B) # segments

intersection_point_list = []

for G in S.geoms:
    
    P = G.boundary.geoms[0] # starting point of segment
    if P not in intersection_point_list and P.distance(P0)>1e-6:
        intersection_point_list.append(P)
        
    P = G.boundary.geoms[1] # end point of segment
    if P not in intersection_point_list and P.distance(P0)>1e-6:
        intersection_point_list.append(P)
        
    
Px = [Pi.coords[0][0] for Pi in intersection_point_list]
Py = [Pi.coords[0][1] for Pi in intersection_point_list]


## finding pre-image of intersection points (work around method for step 3)

def sfunc(t):
    ts = (np.pi-np.abs(t))*np.sign(t)
    return [t, t-2*np.pi, t+2*np.pi, t-4*np.pi, t+4*np.pi, ts, ts-2*np.pi, ts+2*np.pi, ts-4*np.pi, ts+4*np.pi]


axs[1].plot(Px, Py, 'ro')


px = []
py = []
for ux, uy in zip(np.arcsin(Px), np.arcsin(Py)):
    temp_x = sfunc(ux)
    temp_y = sfunc(uy)
    temp_xx, temp_yy = np.meshgrid(temp_x, temp_y)
    temp_xx = temp_xx.flatten()
    temp_yy = temp_yy.flatten()
    temp_dist = [b.distance(sh.Point(tx/f, ty/f)) for tx, ty in zip(temp_xx, temp_yy)]
    
    for idx in [k for k, tk in enumerate(temp_dist) if tk<1e-3]:
        px.append(temp_xx[idx]/f)
        py.append(temp_yy[idx]/f)


axs[2].set_title('original with pre-image of intersect.')
axs[2].plot(x,y)
axs[2].plot(px, py, 'ro')


for ax in axs:
    ax.axis('equal')
```